# Angular form over multiple tabs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular 8 form that spans over 4 tabs, each one has its own form and you need to fill out each question on each tab to be able to unlock the button to save. But I am able to just go to the fourth tab and input those questions and then save and submit the entire thing but without the answers to the first 3 tabs. Is there anyway I can stop this? Maybe have a modal pop up and tell the user they have not completed all the questions

Comment: Hi Luke, please provide us with some code examples and working plunkr or stackblitz to assist you

Comment: keep the tabs disabled until all the previous tabs have been successfully completed? Which would basically lead to you a multi-step form approach

Comment: @bracco23 yeah I had this idea but then when I tried to make the tabs enabled through typescript code, so they would start disabled then when click submit of the first tab the second would then be enabled, but this didn't make the tab enabled.

Comment: @LukeHarland are you trying to submit data only tab at time  or all at one time

Comment: I am saving each of the tabs data and then submitting it once the fourth tabs submit button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
formgroup: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formgroup = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('' , [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      lastName: new FormControl('' , [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      email: new FormControl('' , [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
      ])
    });
  }
formSubmit() {
    if (this.formgroup.valid) {
      // Perform form submit task here get all fields values as
      // this.formgroup.value
    }
  }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formgroup" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()">
 <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active p-3" id="one" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="one-tab">
              <h5 class="card-title">First Name</h5>
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="txtFirstName" formControlName="firstName">
              <button [disabled]="formgroup.controls.firstName.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tab" href="#two" role="tab" aria-controls="Two">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade p-3" id="two" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="two-tab">
              <h5 class="card-title">Last Name</h5>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="txtLastName" formControlName="lastName">
              <button [disabled]="formgroup.controls.lastName.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tab" href="#three" role="tab" aria-controls="Three">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade p-3" id="three" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="three-tab">
              <h5 class="card-title">Email</h5>
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="txtEmail" formControlName="email">
              <button  [disabled]="formgroup.controls.email.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tab" href="#four" role="tab" aria-controls="Four">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade p-3" id="four" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="four-tab">
              <h5 class="card-title">Password</h5>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="txtPassword" formControlName="password">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" [disabled]="formgroup.invalid">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```